# is it possible to change the extension of a cookie file using javascript?

Tags: javascript

is it possible to change the extension of a cookie file using javascript ???

Comment: Please expand your question. What Is the problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: No. (A short non-detailed question gets a short non-detailed answer :P)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on the browser, persistent cookies will be stored differently on the client computer. Some browsers might even store cookies in a database. Using javascript it is not possible to control this and most importantly you don't need to.

Answer (score 3):

Cookies are managed by the browser. You have no direct access to the underlying file. It may not even saved in a file.